# Is it possible to get better screen recording performance on screenrecord via adb?

Tags: android, adb, recording, screen-recording

I try to record screen from my AVD device which specs are:

```
Name: Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5-0
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86_64)
Path: /Users/F1sherKK/.android/avd/Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5-0.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)
Skin: nexus_5x
SD Card: 100M
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 5X
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 23
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86_64/
tag.id: google_apis
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5-0
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 420
avd.ini.displayname: Test-Emulator-API23-Nexus-5-0
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:1be89bc42ec9644d4b77968b23474980
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

I use this command to trigger recording:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 --verbose --size 1280x720 /sdcard/test_recordings/test.mp4
```

I tried various screen resolutions and bitrates from small (1Mbps to 20Mbps).

All the time output of the recording is not smooth at all and lagging a lot.

Example video: https://streamable.com/xxvvh

Is it possible to improve the smoothness of the recording?